How to Derive the Born-Mayer Equation?
Born-Mayer Equation: $E_{P,min}=-A\frac{N_A|z_1z_2|e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0d}(1-\frac{d^*}{d})$
Here is where I have gotten:
$$
E_P=-A\frac{N_A|z_1z_2|e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0d}, E_P^*=N_AC'e^{-d/d^*}\\
$$
Energy minimized when $\frac{d(E_P+E_P^*)}{dd}=0$
$$A\frac{N_A|z_1z_2|e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0d^2}-\frac{C'N_A}{d^*}e^{-d/d^*}=0\\
A\frac{N_A|z_1z_2|e^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0d^2}=\frac{C'N_A}{d^*}e^{-d/d^*}$$
I tried taylor expanding $\frac{C'N_A}{d^*}e^{-d/d^*}\approx \frac{C'N_A}{d^*}(1-\frac{d}{d^*})$, but I don't think that this approximation is appropriate since d/d* is not very small, and it didn't take me anywhere.

There's no need to Taylor expand; the exponential cancels exactly.
Starting with the following (lattice-constant dependent) expression for the total ionic energy:
\begin{equation}
E_P(r) = -\frac{AN_Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0r} + CN_A{}e^{-\left(\frac{r}{d^{*}}\right)}
\end{equation}
where $N_A$ is the Avogadro constant, $e$ is the electron charge, $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the charges of the interacting ions, $A$ is the (geometric) Madelung constant, and $r$ is the lattice parameter, we aim to compute the relative factor $C$ between the attractive term and the repulsive term by imposing the condition that the derivative of the total interaction energy with respect to coordinate (lattice constant) vanishes at equilibrium ($r = d$).
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}E_P}{\mathrm{d}r}\bigg|_{r=d}
= \frac{AN_Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0{}d^2} - \frac{1}{d^{*}}CN_A{}e^{-\left(\frac{r}{d^{*}}\right)}
= 0
\end{equation}
This results in the following expression for $C$:
\begin{equation}
C = \frac{Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0{}d}\left(\frac{d^{*}}{d}\right)
 e^{\left(\frac{r}{d^{*}}\right)}
\end{equation}
and substituting into the original expression for $E_P$ evaluated at equilibrium, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
E_P(d) = -\frac{AN_Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0d}
\left(
1 - \left( \frac{d}{d^{*}} \right)
e^{-\left(\frac{d}{d^{*}}\right)}
e^{\left(\frac{d}{d^{*}}\right)}
\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E_P(d) = -\frac{AN_Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0d}
\left(
1 - \left( \frac{d}{d^{*}} \right)
e^{\left(-\frac{d}{d^{*}} + \frac{d}{d^{*}} \right)}
\right)
\end{equation}
which simplifies to the following:
\begin{equation}
E_P(d) = -\frac{AN_Ae^2|z_1z_2|}{4\pi{}\epsilon_0d}
\left(
1 - \frac{d}{d^{*}}
\right)
\end{equation}
